# Router.go does not redirect in Template.events

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Routes.js:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: "defaultLayout",
  before: function () {
    if(!Meteor.user()) {
      this.layout("loginLayout");
      this.render('login');
    }else{
      this.layout("defaultLayout");
      this.next();
    }
  }
});

Router.route('/',function(){
  this.render('login');
  this.layout('loginLayout');
});

Router.route('/botlist',{
  template: "projects",
  name: "projects",
  data: function(){
    return Projects.find({});
  },    
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('projects',Session.get("username"));
  }
});
```

I have a login page whose js looks like:

```
....
  'click #btn-login'(e, t) {
    var username = $('#email').val(),password = $('#password').val();
    Meteor.call('loginWithad',username,password,function(err,response){
      if(response.err){
        ..              }
      else{
        Meteor.call('finishLogin',username,password,function(err,res){
          if(err){
            ...
          }
          else{
            Session.set("username",res.givenName);
            Router.go("/botlist"); //--> this router.go doesn't route to /botlist template                           
          }
        })
      ....
```

Any issue on my router definition? I have tried multiple solutions none worked :

1. `this.redirect()`
2. `Router.push`
3. `this.stop()` then `Router.go()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the name of the route as the parameter. So:

change

```
Router.go("/botlist");
```

into

```
Router.go("projects");
```